# Image convolution with a Gaussian Blur, speedups possible?

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv3.0

Just as a preface, this is a homework question, but I've finished it, it's just slow.  That doesn't matter for the report.  But I'm trying to speed it up anyways.

So I am trying to apply a guassian blur to an image

```
const unsigned char KERNAL_SIZE = 5;
const unsigned char KERNAL_MEAN = KERNAL_SIZE / 2;
const unsigned char GaussianBlurKernal[KERNAL_SIZE][KERNAL_SIZE] =
{ { 1, 4, 7, 4, 1 },
{ 4, 16, 26, 16, 4 },
{ 7, 26, 41, 26, 7 },
{ 4, 16, 26, 16, 4 },
{ 1, 4, 7, 4, 1 }
};
const int GAUSSIAN_KERNAL_SIZE = 273;
```

and going through the following code:

```
Mat CustomGuassianBlur(const Mat & inputImage)
{
    Size maxSize = inputImage.size();
    Mat outputImage(maxSize, CV_8UC1, Scalar(0, 0, 0));
    for (int i = 0; i < maxSize.width; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < maxSize.height; j++)
        {
            unsigned int sum = 0;
            for (int k = -KERNAL_MEAN; k <= KERNAL_MEAN; k++)
            {
                for (int l = -KERNAL_MEAN; l <= KERNAL_MEAN; l++)
                {
                    Point imagePoint = { (i + l + maxSize.width) % maxSize.width, (j + k + maxSize.height) % maxSize.height };
                    sum = sum + inputImage.at<uchar>(imagePoint) * GaussianBlurKernal[k + KERNAL_MEAN][l + KERNAL_MEAN];
                }
            }
            sum = sum / GAUSSIAN_KERNAL_SIZE;
            outputImage.at<uchar>(j, i) = uchar(sum);
        }
    }
return outputImage;
}
```

The filter takes around 8 seconds.  OpenCV's code of what I'm trying to approximate:

```
GaussianBlur(src_gray, detected_edges, Size(5, 5), 0, 0);
```

Takes less than a quarter second on the same image.

What in particular can I do to speed up the process?  I've read a bit about applying two 1-d filters, but I honestly couldn't understand it all that well.  I've also read a bit about doing the FFT of the image and the filter, multiplying them, and then taking the IFFT, but I don't think that's whats I want to do here: the resources I found mentioned that'd only be more efficient when it comes to larger filters.

Comment: I don't know anything about OpenCV, but your code will call `inputImage.at<uchar>(imagePoint)` twenty five times for each pixel in the image.  If OpenCV won't give you raw pointers to the pixel array, maybe you could make your own raw array, and fill it by calling `inputImage.at<uchar>(imagePoint)` just _one_ time for each pixel.

Comment: It's also worth noting that OpenCV will take advantage of GPUs when they're available, which can be significantly faster for operations like convolution. To more directly compare with OpenCV, you could try to disable that optimization.

Comment: Check out @CostantinoGrana 's answer below. What's probably really killing you is #3. My advice: switch the order of your loops, get a pointer to the entire row with `Mat.ptr` instead of `at`, and remeasure to see how much more you need/want to optimize. Next step in my opinion would be to rewrite as a linear separable filter. Ie: two passes: one over the rows and one over the columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My few cents:

1. Please call your index variables `r` and `c` so that you know what is row and what is column. It will help you in the long run.
2. KERNAL? Shouldn't this be KERNEL? Or is this another language?
3. Remember your cache: your matrix is stored in row-major order, so for each row go through every column.
4. If your kernel size is fixed, unroll the inner double loop.
5. If your kernel size has to change, take the address of the current row with [`cv::Mat::ptr()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a13acd320291229615ef15f96ff1ff738) in the one but inner loop to at least save some computation in the column indexing.
6. Modulus width and height doesn't sound right. You're using a toroidal image representation. Unusual.

Comment: 1) Good idea, thanks
2) I'm not the greatest at spelling, please don't kill me over it.
3) I'll try that out.
4) It's going to be expanded to a arbitrary sized kernel in the future.
6) Part of the requirements, it's a tiled image.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @CostantinoGrana 's answer I want to point out that 2D Gaussian smoothing is linearly separable. Instead of using a 2D kernel, you can use 2 1D kernels -- making a first pass over the rows and a second pass over the columns.

Additionally, if you have access to multiple cores, you could do the 1D filter on the rows / columns in parallel. See the `cv::parallel_for_` construct.

Comment: And how exactly do you use 2 1D kernels?  I'm a little bit confused.  Do you convolute with both of them and just add the results?  Or do you multiply the results?

Comment: Usually this way: 1) Perform a 1D filter over the rows of your source image and call the output `rowFiltered`, 2) Perform a 1D filter over the columns of the `rowFiltered` image and write to your destination.

Comment: @ChrisPy also take a look at `cv::parallel_for_`